# Can a small amount of super-compressed gas cause much cooling upon rapid expansion and contact?

Tags: projectile, gas, adiabatic

Generally, a small amount of mass in the range of $0.001$ - $0.01$ kg, even if chilled to tens of degrees *below* absolute zero in a hypothetical case to test extremes, even with 5000 specific heat and instantaneous transfer of heat to equilibrium temperature, cannot generally be expected to bring a person's entire arm temperature down by more than a degree when coming into contact with someone's arm. This can be derived from an apparently nameless equation $Q = mcT.$ Hooray for us!

However, should I expect this result to be different for super-compressed liquified gas? Is it possible that, say, $0.05$kg of super super super compressed gas, could expand very rapidly over a wide surface area of someone's arm and chill the entire arm by $10$ degrees?

Comment: Temperature is a measure of the average kinetic energy of molecules in a substance.  When that average kinetic energy is zero, the substance is at a temperature of 0 K.  You can't get to a lower temperature than that because there is no more kinetic energy to remove from the substance's molecules.

Comment: What does "super super super compressed" mean?

Comment: @DavidWhite I know that you can't go lower than 0K based on known physics, that's why I said it's hypothetical...

Comment: @DavidWhite Slightly beyond what the most sophisticated known technology can achieve, what we'd expect in the reasonable future of the next 50 years.

Comment: 50g of liquid nitrogen (super-compressed liquified gas) doesn't do much to your arm.

Comment: If you poured 10 grams of liquid helium on your arm, I guarantee the area it touched would drop much more than a degree. As for cooling the whole arm, that's kinda like asking if we'll ever be able to dye all the oceans a different color using only some advanced dye that fits in a 1 Liter bottle.  There just isn't enough there (energy in this case) to do what you want, as you can calculate with $Q=mc\Delta T$

Answer (score 1):

If you took the 10 g of hydrogen and burned it, or compressed it till it was so hot it fused to helium, and then used that energy to power a cooling cycle that was put to work on your arm, you could do it. So in a sense it's possible.

Comment: Okay, so outside of the specified mass range then.